# How can I create a MessageDialog using winrt-rs?

Tags: rust, windows-runtime

I am attempting to show a MessageDialog upon keypress. So far, it doesn't seem to do anything. The code does compile, but does not function. The code verifies that the keypress works, but the dialog simply wont display. I have tried taking the returned IAsyncOperation and using 'get()' but that seems to freeze the application completely. What am I missing?

```
//#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]
use winit::{
    event::{Event, WindowEvent},
    event_loop::{ControlFlow, EventLoop},
    window::WindowBuilder,
};

use winrt::*;
import!(
    dependencies
        os
    modules
        "windows.data.xml.dom"
        "windows.foundation"
        "windows.ui"
        "windows.ui.popups"
);

fn main() {
    let event_loop = EventLoop::new();
    let window = WindowBuilder::new().build(&event_loop).unwrap();
    event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        *control_flow = ControlFlow::Wait;
        match event {
            Event::WindowEvent {
                event: WindowEvent::CloseRequested,
                window_id,
            } if window_id == window.id() => *control_flow = ControlFlow::Exit,
            Event::WindowEvent {
                event: WindowEvent::Resized (_size),
                ..
            } => (),
            Event::WindowEvent {
                event: WindowEvent::KeyboardInput {input,..},
                ..
            } if input.state == winit::event::ElementState::Pressed => {
                use windows::ui::popups::MessageDialog;
                let mymsg = MessageDialog::create("Test").unwrap().show_async();
                println!("KeyState-{}",input.scancode);
            },
            _ => (),
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This highlights one of the differences in using some WinRT APIs in a Win32 application. In a UWP application, your app has a `CoreWindow` associated with its main thread. Normally, dialogs query for this window and display themselves as modal to it. However, in a Win32 application the system can't make an assumption about what window you want to use. In these instances, you need to QI for the [`IInitializeWithWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iinitializewithwindow) interface and call the initialize function with your window handle.

Since the IInitializeWithWindow interface is a pure COM interface and not a WinRT one, winrt-rs doesn't have a projection for it. Instead you'll need to define it yourself (make sure you get the GUID right!):

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct abi_IInitializeWithWindow {
    __base: [usize; 3],
    initialize: extern "system" fn(
        winrt::NonNullRawComPtr<InitializeWithWindowInterop>,
        *mut c_void,
    ) -> winrt::ErrorCode,
}

unsafe impl winrt::ComInterface for InitializeWithWindowInterop {
    type VTable = abi_IInitializeWithWindow;

    fn iid() -> winrt::Guid {
        winrt::Guid::from_values(1047057597, 28981, 19728, [128, 24, 159, 182, 217, 243, 63, 161])
    }
}

#[repr(transparent)]
#[derive(Default, Clone)]
pub struct InitializeWithWindowInterop {
    ptr: winrt::ComPtr<InitializeWithWindowInterop>,
}

impl InitializeWithWindowInterop {
    pub fn initialize(
        &self,
        window: *mut c_void,
    ) -> winrt::Result<()> {
        match self.ptr.abi() {
            None => panic!("The `this` pointer was null when calling method"),
            Some(this) => unsafe {
                (this.vtable().initialize)(
                    this,
                    window,
                )
                .ok()?;
                Ok(())
            },
        }
    }
}
```

To get the window handle from your winit Window, you'll need the [`raw-window-handle`](https://crates.io/crates/raw-window-handle) crate. From there you can create a helper trait for anything that implements `HasRawWindowHandle`:

```rust
trait InitializeWithWindow {
    fn initialize_with_window<O: RuntimeType + ComInterface>(&self, object: &O) -> winrt::Result<()>;
}

impl<T> InitializeWithWindow for T
where
    T: HasRawWindowHandle,
{
    fn initialize_with_window<O: RuntimeType + ComInterface>(
        &self,
        object: &O,
    ) -> winrt::Result<()> {
        // Get the window handle
        let window_handle = self.raw_window_handle();
        let window_handle = match window_handle {
            raw_window_handle::RawWindowHandle::Windows(window_handle) => window_handle.hwnd,
            _ => panic!("Unsupported platform!"),
        };

        let init: InitializeWithWindowInterop = object.try_into()?;
        init.initialize(window_handle)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Now in your event loop you can call it using the following:

```rust
let dialog = MessageDialog::create("Test").unwrap();
window.initialize_with_window(&dialog).unwrap();
dialog.show_async().unwrap();
println!("KeyState-{}",input.scancode);
```

Note that I'm not waiting on the result of the `IAsyncOperation` that is retunred by show_async. The reason is because only synchronous waiting it supported by the projection right now, and that would tie up your message pump and cause the window to hang. This means that the print statement will run before the dialog returns. This should improve once broader async support is up and running in the projection.

You can now use your `initialize_with_window` method on dialogs and pickers (e.g. FileSavePicker, GraphicsCapturePicker).

Comment: Thank you! I have actually been studying your Minesweeper example. I was disappointed there were no pop-ups there to review. I will take this and work towards improving my understanding. Much appreciated!